# Refactor regular C++ code pattern

Tags: c++, refactoring, c-preprocessor

**Summary**: I'm trying to see if I can refactor some C++ code that has a regular pattern to make it easier to update and maintain.

**Details**:

I have some code that creates thread local counters to keep track of statistics during program execution.  Currently when a statistic is added to the source code there are 5 things that need to be updated: the counter thread local declaration, the counter total declaration, a function to reset the thread counters, a function to add the thread counters to the total, and a print function.

The code is something like the following:

```
// Adding a statistic named 'counter'

// Declaration of counter
__thread int counter = 0;
int total_counter = 0;

// In reset function
counter = 0;

// In add function
total_counter += counter;

// In print function
printf("counter value is: %d\n", total_counter);
```

I can see how a macro could be created for the declaration of the counter doing something like:

```
#define STAT(name) __thread int name; \
                   int total_##name;
```

But I haven't thought of how this could be extended to also update the `add` and `reset` functions.  Ideally I'd like to type something like `STAT(counter)` and have all the declarations and functions for managing the statistic taken care of.

**Edit**:

I already have macros for updating the statistics in the code.  Something so that something like `STAT_INC(counter)` will increment the local counter value.  Then when the thread finished execution it's thread local values are added to the overall total.  So the name of each statistic is important so that is why an array would not work well for me.  Because the real counter names are things like `cache_hit` which be more meaningful than `counter[2]` and I don't want to lose the ability to have arbitrary names for the statistics that are created.  Just to simplify the amount of code I have to write when declaring a statistic if possible.

Comment: Use an array (or vector, or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This keeps more or less what you described in your question encapsulated in a template class:

```
enum StatNames {
    STAT_rx_bytes,
    STAT_tx_bytes,
    //...,
};

template <StatNames SN>
class Stat {
    static const char *name_;
    static __thread int x_;
    static int total_;

public:
    Stat(const char *name) { name_ = name; }
    static void reset () { x_ = 0; }
    static void add () { total_ += x_; }
    static void print () {
        std::cout << name_ << " value is: " << total_ << "\n";
    }
    static int & x () { return x_; }
    static int total () { return total_; }
};

template <StatNames SN> const char * Stat<SN>::name_;
template <StatNames SN> __thread int Stat<SN>::x_;
template <StatNames SN> int Stat<SN>::total_;

#define STAT(name) Stat<STAT_##name> name(#name)
```

You could then write code like the following:

```
STAT(rx_bytes);

void * test (void *)
{
    rx_bytes.x() += 4;
    rx_bytes.add();
    std::cout << pthread_self() << ": " << rx_bytes.x() << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t t[2];
    pthread_create(&t[0], 0, test, 0);
    pthread_create(&t[1], 0, test, 0);
    pthread_join(t[0], 0);
    pthread_join(t[1], 0);
    rx_bytes.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Nobody answered after 7 minutes... I get the gift!)

So basically you don't want five separate named variables. You can use an array or vector:

```
int counters[5];
```

Then it's very easy to update a certain counter:

```
class Counter {
    int counters[5];
    void update_nth(int n)
    {
        counters[n]++;
    }
};
```

Similarly with all the other variables.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I might not have explained it well enough in my question. I'd like to be able to declare the counters with arbitrary names like `foo` or `bar`. Then I have functions that are already called at certain points for totaling up the thread local `foo` values. I might not understand your answer but I don't think it allows me to define new variables with an arbitrary name (which is important for having the code be self-documented).

Comment: @Gabriel If you really want some refactoring, then you can't have names **and** automatic/unified updating (unless you wrap the entire stuff in an enornous `switch-case`, but that'd be a total failure.)

Comment: thanks for the comment and answer.  Even if I can't do better than what I have now it's useful to know that I'm not missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Following up H2CO3's answer, there's a common idiom which looks like this:

```
enum CounterEnums {
    MyFirstCounter,
    MySecondCounter,
    // ... add new counter names here ...
    NumCounters
};
class Counter {
    int counters[NumCounters];
public:
    void update(int n) { counters[n]++; }
};
```

Now, you can add another counter easily, just put it *before* `NumCounters`. Now, you can just declare your instances, something like:

```
Counter totals; // global
boost::thread_specific_pointer<Counter> counters; // per-thread
```

and use

```
counters->update(MyFirstCounter);
```

(you'll also need a some way to update `totals` and zero your per-thread counters, but I'll ... leave that as an exercise for the reader).